# Is it possible to define an apache POI OPCPackage with enforced encoding?

Tags: java, encoding, apache-poi, inputstream, xlsx

I have an xlsx File from which I want to read data. Since I'm using apache POI, I need to use OPCPackage object to do my analysis. but for some reason I am not getting the correct data with bellow code.

I cannot use the simple sheet iterating method, since for that I need to load the whole sheet, and in my case it happens that I would receive sheets with size of 4-5 Gbs which would cause the server to fail. So the last resource is to use OPCPackage and ReadOnlySharedStringsTable.

```
public parseXlsx(String path, String fileName) throws Exception {
     File file = new File(path, fileName);
     OPCPackage xlsxPackage = OPCPackage.open(file.getAbsolutPath());
     ReadOnlySharedStringsTable stringTables = new ReadOnlySharedStringsTable(xlsxPackage);
     //bunch of other things
}
```

when debugging, when I check the value of stringTables, it is already faulty, holding extra characters and faulty values. I know it is possible to path an InputStream to `OPCPackage.open` method. but is it also possible to enforce the encoding? since my only doubt is that I have encoding problem here.

Thanks

Comment: Are you aware of how the String Table works? (And doesn't work)?

Comment: Not exactly, this is a code I have to modify and the first time I come across apache OPI.

Comment: It's rather unusual to go straight for the Shared Strings table, that's pretty advanced usage. Is there a reason why you're not starting with the Apache POI tutorials, eg [Getting Cell Contents](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CellContents) and [Iterating over Rows and Cells](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator)?

Comment: I see your point, but as I said it is a code that we rather not modify significantly. so I was hoping to continue using sharedStringTables but with supervision over encoding of the data.

Comment: The SST should already be correctly encoded, as it's all XML. I think your problem is that it may not contain what you expect it to contain...

Comment: The problem is that it holds everything the way it should, just for one particular field (which is a japanese word) it adds some extra characters at the end!